# List of list in json convert to table in html with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, frontend, jinja2

For rendering html table I transfer from the Flask application to the HTML page a python list of lists of the following form:

`table_data = [['Paris', 17, 0, 0, 0], ['London', 14, 0, 0, 0], ...]`

When I render a page, I create a table using the following code with Jinja:

```
<table class="table" id="mydatatable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">City</th>
        <th scope="col">Count1</th>
        <th scope="col">Count2</th>
        <th scope="col">Count3</th>
        <th scope="col">Count4</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
    {% for list in table_data %}
    <tr>
      {% for row in list %}
      <td> {{row}} </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But also I should update data of this table and I don’t want to reload the page, but just to update the data in this table. So I decided to send JSON to this table of following format:

`{table_data: [['Mexico', 20, 0, 0, 0], ['Madrid', 21, 0, 0, 0], ...]}`

But how to update table data in HTML using JS and correctly delete old rows and insert new ones?

Maybe I should use the loop with JS?

Comment: If you don't want to reload the page, create an api endpoint in your flask app to post/get data from. If you stay 100% jinja and python, you're going to have to reload the page to get your updates. If you introduce JavaScript and post/get endpoints, you can do it.

Comment: @furas that's why i am here

Comment: but it is not place to learn JavaScript but to resolve problems with errors in code.

Comment: You would want to create everything as DOM Elements using a function that returns `document.createElement(tagName);`, so you can add Events before appending to the DOM and still have access to the DOM Elements for the update. So, you'll want to learn Constructors and/or classes.